# Filter "terms aggregation" by key length

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an ES index that contains parameter data from some scientific experiments.

I have the following terms aggregation:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "variables": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "value",
                "size": 100
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Which returns a result like this:

```
{
    "took" : 3,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 9928,
        "max_score" : 0.0,
        "hits" : [ ]
    },
    "aggregations" : {
        "variables" : {
            "buckets" : [ {
                "key" : "00",
                "doc_count" : 158
            }, {
                "key" : "1",
                "doc_count" : 158
            }, {
                "key" : "2",
                "doc_count" : 158
            }, {
                "key" : "pressure",
                "doc_count" : 158
            }, {
                "key" : "seconds",
                "doc_count" : 158
            }, {
                "key" : "since",
                "doc_count" : 158
            }, {
                "key" : "s",
                    "doc_count" : 156
            }, {
                "key" : "speed",
                    "doc_count" : 127
            }, {
                "key" : "sample",
                    "doc_count" : 121
            }, {
                "key" : "a",
                    "doc_count" : 104
            } ]
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is tell ElasticSearch to ignore all keys with a length smaller than 5;

e.g. to filter out `"key": "a"`, `"key": "s"`, and so on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I solved the problem. I re-indexed the data using a custom analyzer, which reads as follows:

`PUT $host/$index`:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "min_length_5_filter": {
                    "type": "length",
                    "min": 5,
                    "max": 256
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "variable_name_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                    "filter": ["min_length_5_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the index mapping:

`PUT $host/$index/_mapping/$mapping_name`:

```
...
"parameters": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "variable_name_analyzer"
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "variable_name_analyzer"
        }
    }
},
...
```

Using the method above, filtering tokenized strings using a minimum length allowed me to remove a lot of junk values and now the "terms aggregation" works really well. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a [Regexp Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html) to have the wanted result:

```
    "filter": {
        "regexp":{
            "value" : ".{2,}"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks!

The problem is that the variables are stored in sentences; e.g. "Seconds past 1970-01-01 00:00:00" or "Wind speed (miles per hour)".

Instead, I will try using a custom analyzer to index the different terms, and filter any keys that have a length of < 5 characters.